# What is this animation about?

Tags: geometry

I saw this animation on a math telegram channel and I am curios to know what rule  of mathematic showed. We have a triangle at the end look like an equilateral triangle.

https://videoshome.com.au/Home/Play/5fcd58e63d68540841b3a998

Comment: Euclidean ruler and compass construction of a pentagon.

Comment: @SenZen we have triangle at the end.

Comment: triangles are special types of pentagons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows how to construct an equilateral triangle with a centre at a given point. This is different to the construction of an equilateral triangle given one side, which is a much simpler task.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you!